# Como imprimir la palabra que esta a un lado de una palabra en especifico de un richtextbox a otro? c#

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo en este mundo de C# y estoy encontrando muchos problemas con una funcion que quiero realizar.

Lo que deseo conseguir es, por ejemplo: en un richtextbox tengo la oracion (Deporte: "Natacion")
lo que busco es que en otro richtextbox me imprima solamente la palabra que esta adentro de las comillas (en este caso "Natacion") mediante un boton.

Me percate que usar Regex era la mejor manera de separar palabras por patrones y demas...

Pero tengo un problema, y es que cada vez que ejecuto la funcion por el boton, me lee solo la primera coincidencia, es decir:

En el richtextbox 1 tengo:
Deporte: "Natacion"
\nDeporte: "Ciclismo"
\nDeporte: "Atletismo".
(siempre una oracion bajo la otra)

En el richtextbox 2 me aparece:
"Natacion".

Cuando en realidad necesito que me aparezcan todas las palabras que encuentra adentro de las comillas.

Este es el codigo de la funcion:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"");
            Match match = regex.Match(GetRichTextBox().Text);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                cmSalida.Text = match.Value;
            }
        }
```

En donde cmSalida es el richtextbox 2 donde quiero que aprezcan las palabras entre comillas y GetRichTextBox() es el metodo que utilizo para crear el richtextbox 1 donde siempre estara el texto inicial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás buscando una sola aparición del patrón, por ello sólo te da un resultado. Deberías capturar un valor en la expresión y recorrer todas las capturas:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(Texto, @"""([^""]+)"""))
    System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].ToString());
```

---

#### La expresión [`"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ZJQXGl/1).

Los paréntesis son una captura de valor; puedes ver en la expresión regular que capturará de 1 a ∞ caracteres que no sean comillas (`"`) y que estén entre comillas.

#### El literal `@"""([^""]+)"""`.

El lenguaje [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) permite escribir literales de texto en crudo, [según la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) usando una arroba (`@`) como prefijo para el literal de texto (traducción mía):

> Para indicar que un literal de cadena de caracteres debe ser interpretado como literal de cadena de caracteres [verbatim](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbatim). Las [secuencias de escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) simples (como `"\\"` para barra descendente), secuencias de escape hexadecimales (como `"\x0041"` para A mayúscula) y secuencias de escape Unicode (como `"\u0041"` para A mayúscula) se interpretan literalmente. Únicamente la secuencia de las comillas (`""`) no se interpreta de manera literal; produce una sola comilla.

Usando el literal en crudo, te ahorras el escapar las secuencias de escape de la expresión regular.

#### La colección de coincidencias (*matches*).

Dado que quieres obtener todas las coincidencias que sigan un patrón, necesitarás las coincidencias (*matches*) en **plural**. El motor de expresiones regulares de [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) te permite acceder a ello mediante `Regex.Matches` que devuelve una colección de coincidencias (*match*) con el patrón recibido como segundo parámetro; cada elemento de la colección tiene a su vez grupos siendo siempre el primer grupo (el cero) la coincidencia completa y los grupos posteriores las sub-capturas de la coincidencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Ahora me lee todas las coincidencias, respecto a "match.Groups[1].ToString()" que tal si en vez de .ToString(), lo reemplazo por .Value? veo que me arrojan los mismos resultados, pero en si, desconozco la funcionalidad en especifico del .Value, De nuevo, Gracias!

Comment: El `ToString()` al final de los grupos de las coincidencias es sólo ilustrativo para que veas el código funcionando, sustitúyelo por aquello que te sea más conveniente.